# Javascript Sharepoint Presaveaction always getting var undefined

Tags: javascript, validation, sharepoint

I need to do a validation inside the PreSaveAction if a field (demofield) is equal to yes, if so call a function called ViewItem and ViewItem checks if a value exists or not and change the value of "result" to Yes or NO; result is also a global variable. But for some reason when I change the value of "result" inside the "success" function it doesnt change for the global variable "result". What am I doing wrong or is there any other way to make this validation happen?

```js
var result; // This is always undefined

function ViewItem()
{

var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('demoTrainingRoom2');
var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
allItems = list.getItems(query);
context.load(allItems, 'Include(Title, EventDate, time2)');

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
}



function success() {

var currentTitle = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('EventDate').GetValue(); 
for(var i = 0; i < this.allItems.get_count(); i++){
      var item = this.allItems.get_item(i);
      console.log(item.get_item('time2') + ' - ' + currentTitle );
                           
                     if (currentTitle == item.get_item('time2')){
                    
                    
                     this.result = "Yes"; //// here is where i change the value of result

      alert('There is an event with the same Start Date on DemoTrainingRoom2' + ' ' + item.get_item('time2') + ' - ' + currentTitle + ' ' + result);
                                         
                     return true; // or item
                     
                                                             
          }
      }
      
                  this.result = "No"; // here is where i change the value of result
      alert("No event yet");    
      return false;
      

    }
    
function failed(sender, args) {
alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
}


function PreSaveAction()    {


var time = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('EventDate').GetValue();
alert(time + " Current Start Time ");


if(SPUtility.GetSPField('demoField').GetValue() == "no")
{
     
     alert('No need for validation');
     return true;
    }
    

   else if(SPUtility.GetSPField('demoField').GetValue() == "yes") 
 
   {
   
   ViewItem(); 
   
   if(result == "Yes") // here is here i need the new value of result globlal
    {
  alert(result);

   return false;
   
  }
  
  else
  
  {
  alert(result); // i always get here cuz result global is undefined
 
  return true;
  
  }
  
    } 



}
```

UPDATE

```js
function ViewItem(listTitle, Success, Error) {
 var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var web = context.get_web();
 var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
 var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
 //variable local
 var allItems = list.getItems(query);
 context.load(allItems, 'Include(Title, EventDate, tiempo2)');
 context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
   var currentTitle = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('EventDate').GetValue();
   var res = "No";
   for (var i = 0; i < allItems.get_count(); i++) {
    var item = allItems.get_item(i);
    console.log(item.get_item('tiempo2') + ' - ' + currentTitle );
    if (currentTitle == item.get_item('tiempo2')){
     res = "Si"; // aca segun yo le cambio el valor a result
     console.log('There is an event with the same Start Date on DemoTrainingRoom2' 
      + ' ' + item.get_item('tiempo2') + ' - ' + currentTitle);
              //return true; // or item
          }
   }
   return Success(res);
  },
  Error
 );
}

function PreSaveAction() {
 var time = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('EventDate').GetValue();
 alert(time + " Current Start Time ");
 
 if(SPUtility.GetSPField('demoField').GetValue() == "no") {
  alert('No need for validation');
  return true;
 } 
 else if(SPUtility.GetSPField('demoField').GetValue() == "yes") {
  //llamo a esta pa ver si hay items con valores duplicados
  var res2 = ViewItem('demoTrainingRoom2', function(res){
    console.log('Resultado: ' + res);
    if(res == "Si") //deberia de entrar si result fuera Si
    {
     alert(res);
     return false;
    }
    else
    {
     alert(res); //Pero siempre entra aca por que result es undefined
     return true;
    }  
   },
   function (sender, args) {
    alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
   }
  );
  
  
  return res2;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your success ViewItem() function depends on an asynchronous request, so by the time you check on the result variable, ViewItem's success function has not executed, and its results variable is still unchanged.

You could move the code from inside ViewItem() into your PreSaveAction function and make success() a self-executable anonymous function that would be responsible for PreSaveAction's return.